# Typescript trying update a boolean property in my object receives "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property"

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have object that has been already defined, how can I change the value of a property? Do I have any other alternatives?

```
export interface myTest {
    shouldChange: boolean; // <-- not using readonly
}

const testObj = {
    shouldChange: false
} as myTest;

// later on 
testObj.shouldChange = true // <-- this throws the following error
```

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'shouldChange' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: You are assigning to variable `myTest` instead of `testObject`

Comment: Have you tried not declaring the object as `const`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20myTest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shouldChange%3A%20boolean%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20not%20using%20readonly%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20shouldChange%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%20as%20myTest%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20later%20on%20%0D%0AtestObj.shouldChange%20%3D%20true%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20this%20throws%20the%20following%20error

Comment: The error in your question most likely [happens at runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only), the code you posted is not enough to reproduce it. Could you provide more details about how `testObj` is created and what's happening between `testObj` creation and `// later on` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this code is being used in an NGRX context or not, but eitherway, consider trying the following:

```
testObj = {...testObj};
```

In the NGRX context, the data you get from the store is in a freeze-state and is readonly. With this code (which is the spread operator and the equivalent of `testObj = Object.Assign({}, testObj)`) you basically create a brand new object that looks identical to the previous `testObj`. The only difference is, this object does not have the freeze-state and can be adjusted freely.

If you have deeper objects and you need to adjust those you have to use [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) from lodash

```
export interface myTest {
    shouldChange: boolean;
    somethingElse: DeepObject;
}

export class DeepObject {
    index: number;
}

testObj = _.cloneDeep(testObj);
testObj.somethingElse.index = 42; // <-- Does not throw errors
```

Answer (score 0):

one of options you can do here, is to access to property with `[]` brackets and assign to it type `any`

```
export interface myTest {
    shouldChange: boolean; // <-- readonly
}

const testObj = {
    shouldChange: false
} as myTest;


testObj['shouldChange' as any] = true;
```

Comment: There is no reason this should be necessary .. I can't  reproduce his issue with the given code, can you ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I just reproduced it with adding `readonly` before `shouldChange` property in `myTest` interface, because he wrote that it is `readonly`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, I don't know, but I think he just forgot to add `readonly` before property in the question, otherwise why he should get that error on property  value change ?

Comment: His error seems more like a runtime error as @artem correctly points out ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir hmm it is possible, but we should wait to him :D